# How to debug python logging stack

Tags: python, logging

I've got an issue where a message logged into a module-specific logger does not get displayed from an application. Trying to reproduce the minimal version of the code magically solves the issue.

Trying to list the attributes from the stack of loggers in two places, I get the following:

This one prints out DEBUG messages when logging in `anchor.audit`:

```
# logger, name, level, propagate, helpers
(<logging.Logger object at 0x7ff6cac15850>, 'anchor.audit', 0, True, [])
(<logging.Logger object at 0x7ff6cac15990>, 'anchor', 10, 1, [])
(<logging.RootLogger object at 0x7ff6caccfa10>, 'root', 20, 1, [<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x7ff6c846f310>])
```

This one doesn't print anything, even at ERROR level:

```
# logger, name, level, propagate, helpers
(<logging.Logger object at 0x7ff6c931ac50>, 'oslo_messaging.notify.notifier', 0, 1, [])
(<logging.RootLogger object at 0x7ff6caccfa10>, 'root', 20, 1, [<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x7ff6c846f310>])
```

If at the same place in the `notifier` I replace `_LOG.error` with `_LOG.parent.error`, I confirm that the root logger still works properly.

What else in the logger configuration can affect this? Which options can I look at?